# TCL raw socket multiline response

Tags: sockets, tcl, response, multiline

I am writing test code in environment that uses TCL as a language. After sending command to the device via raw socked I receive response, which is sometimes multiple line (device terminal is not very stable).

Code below shows me only one line. How change it easily to return multiple lines, if response indeed have more than one line?

```
set connection [socket $session_ip $session_port]
puts $connection "my_command_here"
flush $connection
puts [gets $connection]
```

As a workaround I have repeated two last steps

```
    flush $connection
    puts [gets $connection]
```

Unfortunately, in case of only one line response it freezes. Tried to use *read* istead of *gets* but without proper results.

Comment: Define 'without proper results'. Is the peer *sending* lines?

Comment: It freezes without response.

Comment: How do you know the other side has sent a multi-line response? Do you have some code that can look at a line and say “this line has had its end chopped off”? (I ask because that code will make writing the asynchronous handler for reading the input and rebuilding the original lines _much_ easier to write.)

Comment: I know that by manual work on the device - have observed this behavior (responding with one or more lines) many times.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no established protocol for determining how many lines there will be in the response, you will have to use non-blocking input. It is also advisable to use event-based processing:

```
set connection [socket $session_ip $session_port]
# Set the connection to non-blocking and line buffering
fconfigure $connection -blocking 0 -buffering line
# Set up a proc to react to incoming events on the socket
# These can be: Receiving data and the connection being closed
fileevent $connection readable [list eventhandler $connection]

proc eventhandler {fd} {
    if {[eof $fd]} {
        puts "Remote side closed the connection"
        close $fd
    } elseif {[gets $fd line] != -1} {
        puts $line
    }
}

puts $connection "my_command_here"

vwait forever
```

Using event based programming requires a very different way of structuring your program. The subject is too extensive to cover here. Look for further information on the web if you are unfamiliar with the concept.

Comment: If you have 8.6 or later, using coroutines can make writing the async handlers far easier to get right.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I can assume that the range of response lines can be between 1 - 5. In this case, what would be the simplest solution?

Comment: That doesn't make any difference. If it's not a number that can be predetermined, you will need to deal with the uncertainty.